# Problems with calling bash scritpt from octave in ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, octave, ubuntu-20.04

I trying to run a script which invokes a program outside octave. The script works fine when called from terminal. My problem is that the shebang part of the script doesnt seems to invoke bash. For example, if I write the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo $SHELL
whoami
```

When I call this script fom octave

```
system('bash myscript.bash')
```

I got:

```
>> /bin/sh
>> user
```

So when I try to run the actual script from octave (not the one above), I get "command not found" errors.
Any idea what im doing wrong here?

Comment: `from octave (not the one above)` So if not the above, then how do you call the actual script? What for would you show the above?

Comment: Please add to your script: `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`.

Comment: you shouldn't leave a space between the shebang and the path to bash. also, you don't need to call bash in your system call. just make your script executable and call it directly.

Comment: 5.0.11(1)-release

Comment: It is executable, tried to call directly but no difference.

Comment: The "not above code" sould call the solve-field command from astrometry.net package, but drops "command not found error"

Comment: Isn’t `/bin/bash` a link to `/bin/sh` in Ubuntu? I’m pretty sure that they’re both the same binary.

Comment: Why don’t you ask about the "command not found" errors? That might be related to Octave changing your environment, such that either the PATH or the LD_LIBRARY_PATH are not set up to run your executable.

Comment: Because it seemed to me that the problem causing that error is that octave loads sh instead of bash. After echo $PATH in gnome-terminal I added the loadpaths which was missing in octave, but I still got the command not found error. (just for clarification I added the paths with addpath in octave, and also after >>system('bash') I edited ~/.bashrc to load the same missing paths. So gnome-terminal and whatever bash octave is invoking share the same paths, and only gnome-terminal is able to call the Astrometry.net packabe solve-field command.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the issue was that I installed Octave with flatpack, which creates its own environment or something, hence cant really see the functions in /bin. So if you having similar issues, like not having the same functions in Octave command line and Terminal:

```
flatpak uninstall octave
sudo apt-get install octave
```

Answer (score 0):

please try

`system('./myscript.bash')`

or

`system('/bin/sh /root/path/to/myscript.bash')`

and in your bash script use absolute path to your program or you can your program in `/bin` directory

path example:
`/root/path/to/myscript.bash`

Comment: Im still getting the same output
>> /bin/sh
>> user